# Create generic list, whereby type of the list known only at runtime

Tags: java, generics, types

I want to generate a generic list where the type of the list is known only at runtime (its the type of the object, which create that list).

Complete description:

I want to implement this functionality in a abstract class, so i know the parent class before runtime.

Don't know how to do that.

```
    Class myClass = getClass().getSuperclass();
    LinkedList<myClass> list = new LinkedList<myClass>();
```

does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: You can refer this link:- http://blog.xebia.com/2009/02/07/acessing-generic-types-at-runtime-in-java/

Comment: I think the best you can do is make a `LinkedList<Object>`.  Java isn't Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are largely a compile time feature so it doesn't have any meaning in this context.

You can just write

```
List list = new LinkedList();
```

I usually prefer ArrayList if you can use that. ;)

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the question, but should the OP type them as `<?>` if he is actually making them to be used with a variety of classes?

Comment: @Windle: You can't add anything but `null` to a `List<?>`.  The `?` means "an unknown but specific type", not "anything".

Comment: `<?>` means it doesn't know what type it can safely add and `null` is the only value which can be cast to anything. What you get from the list will be an `Object`

Comment: So generics are nice to have for getting errors before / while compiling if operations on a specific type are not allowed? But if i dont know the type before compiling there is no benefit for me?

Comment: @MarkPeters Ya, think I read it wrong.  Wasn't trying to say he could add multiple types to one list though. Thought he wanted to declare the list in an abstract class, hence `<?>`, and then he would initialize it to whatever type he used to extend the abstract. I appreciate the responses though =)

Answer (score 5):

or you can just write:

```
    List<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
```

Comment: +1 I would say this is probably a better option than using raw types, since the Java Language Specification states that raw types may be disallowed in the future. [JLS 4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

Comment: This is creating a list of Objects, rather than of the class resolved at runtime. It's not resolving the question asked unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Non-Generics` **ArrayList**

`ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();`

even you can use the `<?>`

Thought using the `List` will be good, as it show the principle of `"Program in Interface rather than implementation"`

Comment: the reference variable should be List so we program to interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to parametrize the abstract class with the type of the extending class. This is a bit over-engineered, but should work:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class  AbstractListHolder<T> {

    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }

}

class ListHolder extends AbstractListHolder<ListHolder> {

    void doSomething() {
        getList().add(this);        
    }

}
```